# Prevent Keras EarlyStopping from canceling due to early metric spike

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tf.keras

This is an issue I've run into recently when training various models using Keras. Particularly, this occurs often when training on [imbalanced datasets](https://archive.vn/wip/H3N27) -- *archived Medium.com article*

### The Problem

There are times when model fitting begins with a large spike in one or more metrics. The way Keras EarlyStopping works, even if you have `patience` set greater than `0`, it will still record the "best weights" during training *before the patience interval has been reached*.

Hence, siutations like the following can occur ...

[image]

See below for a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

### The (a) Solution

This seems like a silly flaw in the logic, and it's rather easy to correct. One way to do this is by modifying the keras EarlyStopping class's `on_epoch_end` function ...

```py
class PatientEarlyStopping(keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping):
    """
    Equal to vanilla EarlyStopping, but will wait until patience (if set)
    has been exceeded BEFORE logging best value & best weights
    Helps to avoid EarlyStopping being triggered due to early training metric spikes
    """

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        current = self.get_monitor_value(logs)
        if current is None:
            return

        if epoch == self.patience:
            # we've reached self.patience the first time, reset self.wait
            self.wait = 0

        if self.monitor_op(current - self.min_delta, self.best) and epoch >= self.patience:
            # epoch >= self.patience -- a.k.a. don't log the best value until patience is exceeded the first time!
            # no clue why this is not default behavior ...
            self.best = current
            self.wait = 0
            if self.restore_best_weights:
                self.best_weights = self.model.get_weights()
        else:
            self.wait += 1
            if self.wait >= self.patience and epoch >= self.patience:
                self.stopped_epoch = epoch
                self.model.stop_training = True
                if self.restore_best_weights:
                    if self.verbose > 0:
                        print('Restoring model weights from the end of the best epoch.')
                    self.model.set_weights(self.best_weights)
```

Hope this helps others in the future!

Feel free to let me know if there's a reason why it records best value / weights when it hasn't exceeded the `patience` value.